# Wordpress plugin/code to hide all things related of a user from the public

Tags: php, plugins

I am looking for a plugin or a code that will allow admin to hide all things related to a specific user. Not to delete it, just to hide it from the public. Something like to be unable to viewed from the visitors and other users.

This should include posts, author page and comments if it is possible.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: I don't see that this is trivially possible.

Answer (score 1):

Just last week Rilwis, a developer from Vietnam "famous" for his custom-metabox script came with a plugin to hide the menu (or part of it). It's premium, but 9 bucks only, so that shouldn't put a real dent in anybody's budget :) Check it out over at [deluxeblogtips](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/p/wordpress-hide-admin-menu.html)